# how to only 30% payment of order total payment in ubercart in drupal 7?

Tags: ubercart

I am using ubercart module in my site. I need to pay only 30% of order total not fully payment at the time of checkout. For this I am using uc_downpayment module . But I am not getting any option for such type of functionality.

Comment: Did you check [UC Discount Framework](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_discount)?

Comment: I am using drupal 7.. its for drupal 6

Comment: Sorry, just now noticed that I gave you the wrong link. The module I wanted to send initially was [Ubercart Discount Coupon](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_coupon). Did you have any luck with it?

Comment: ohh. this module dont provide such type of functionality .. its a discount module for total price.. not partial payment. :(

Comment: Ages ago I wrote this d6 module:https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_partialpayment . I see now we still need something like that...

Comment: Any other solutions ??